# On the positivity of cotangent bundle of elliptic surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

I am working on the complex numbers field $\mathbb{C}$, for simplicity. However you can relax this assumption if you want.

Let $X$ be an elliptic surface, *id est* there is a proper morphism $\pi\colon X\to C$ of projective varieties, where $C$ is a smooth curve, such that the genus of all smooth fibres is $1$.

**Example.** Let $E$ be an elliptic curve, $X=E\times C$ and $\pi$ is the canonical projection on the second factor. $X$ is an elliptic surface. If $g(C)\geq1$ then $\Omega^1_X$ is *nef*.

**Question.** Are there other examples of elliptic surfaces $X$ such that $\Omega^1_X$ is *nef*? If not, how does one prove the non-existence of these surfaces?

Comment: There are also examples where you form the quotient by an action of a finite group $G$ that acts freely on both $X$ and $C$ such that projection is equivariant.

Comment: @JasonStarr Can you explain some of these examples? Or can you give me a reference? Thank you.